# Finding unique values from Oracle Table TYPE object

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am getting data from a feed file which is stored in Oracle Table TYPE.

Table TYPE created:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE typ_employee AS OBJECT
(
   EMP_NAME DATE,
   EMP_DEPT NUMBER,
   EMP_SALARY NUMBER,
);
/
```

How can I find the unique records from this object and insert in another table.

Please help with this query.

Comment: A type doesn't store anything, so I am not sure what you mean. Can you provide some more details?

Comment: That's an object type, not a table type. Perhaps you have a table of that type? Any way, it would be helpful to explain more about what you need, including sample data and expected results.

Comment: Not clear what you are saying. How can a feed file be stored in Oracle Table TYPE?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested table and then use SET(Nested_table) which gives you distinct records in the nested table.

Or You can insert data from one table to another using cursor and use exception dup_val_on_index in exception block and you can skip that records (primary key should be added in second table) or update the existing one